# What Format is this File (starting with "!R! SEM 9;EXIT;") and how to display it onscreen

Tags: printer, file-format, windows-95

I have the following file found on a customer system and i need to figure out what format it is and (if possible) how to open it in Windows (Win7 or upwards would be perfectly fine).

It sould be some kind of Graphics/Printer format.
The filename holds no extencion and it was generated using Windows 95.

File header:

```
!R! SEM 9;EXIT;
%-12345X@PJL JOB
@PJL SET ECONOMODE=OFF 
@PJL RDYMSG DISPLAY=""
@PJL ENTER LANGUAGE=POSTSCRIPT
M%!PS-Adobe-3.0
%%Title: 
%%Creator: Kyocera Mita FS-1020D KX
%%CreationDate: 10/24/2016 08:45
%%DocumentPrinterRequired: Kyocera Mita FS-1020D KX
%%For: 
%%BoundingBox: (atend)
%%Pages: (atend)
%%Orientation: (atend)
%%PageOrder: Special
%%DocumentNeededResources: (atend)
%%DocumentSuppliedResources: (atend)
%%DocumentData: Clean7Bit
%%LanguageLevel: 2
%%EndComments
%%BeginDefaults
%%PageOrientation: Portrait
%%PageBoundingBox: 12 10 407 587
%%PageMedia: (Plain)
%%EndDefaults
%%BeginProlog
%%BeginResource: Macro_Basic
/KPDLBASE 100 dict dup begin
```

It holds more "%%"-Sections, here without content, as it could be sensitive data:

```
%% Graphics
...
%% Font
...
%% Reencode
...
%% T42
...
end def
%%EndResource
%%EndProlog
%%BeginSetup
KPDLBASE begin
%%BeginFeature: *Resolution 600dpi
BF{
  <</HWResolution [600 600]>> SP
  <</PreRenderingEnhance t>> SP
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *InputSlot (Auto Tray Select)
BF{
<</DeferredMediaSelection t>> SP
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *PageSize (A5)
BF{
  <</Policies <</PageSize 7>> /PageSize [422 595] /ImagingBBox n>> SP
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *MediaType (Automatische Medienauswahl)
BF{
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: Copies 1
BF{
  <</NumCopies 1>> SP
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *Duplex None
BF{
  & ` f setduplexmode E
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *Smoothing ON
BF{
  1 & /setdoret g e
}EF
%%EndFeature
%%BeginFeature: *Collate true
BF{
    userdict /UICollateDetails known not {userdict /UICollateDetails 10 # put} if
    userdict /UICollateDetails g @ /Mode 0 put /Hold 0 put
    <</Collate t /CollateDetails UICollateDetails>> SP
}EF
%%EndFeature
  /DTM [0.12000 0.0 0.0 -0.12000 10 587] d
%%EndSetup
KPDLBASE /PageSV save put
%%Page: 1 1
%%PageOrientation: Landscape
%%PageBoundingBox: (atend)
%%BeginPageSetup
  [0.0 0.12000 0.12000 0.0 12 10] + G
%%EndPageSetup
```

Then it follows ~2500 lines of Content and the following footer:

```
%%PageTrailer
%%PageBoundingBox: 0 0 574 396
/PageSV where { pop PageSV restore } if
%%Trailer
%%Pages: 1
%%Orientation: Portrait Landscape
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 574 396
%%EOF
%-12345X@PJL EOJ
%-12345X
```

EDIT:

Here is the code for a C#-console application that trys to convert all files in a given directory to PDF files. Please note that i didnt do any validation on the given input data.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrintDataToPDF
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Input filepath:");
        string inputDir = Console.ReadLine();

        DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(inputDir);

        Console.WriteLine("Output filepath:");

        string outputDir = Console.ReadLine();

        List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

        foreach (FileInfo item in dir.GetFiles())
        {
            fileList.Add(item);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(fileList.Count + " files found! Convertation is starting..");

        foreach (FileInfo item in fileList)
        {
            string tempname = Path.GetTempFileName();
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(item.FullName))
            {
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(tempname))
                {
                    writer.Write(content.Substring(content.IndexOf("%%")));
                }
                Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.21\bin\gswin64c.exe", "-o " + outputDir + item.Name + "out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite "+ tempname);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " was converted!");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!R!SEM6;EXIT;` is a command used by kyocera printers and copiers (which probably was the printerdriver used to generate this file).

- `!R!` stands for the recognation code for prescribe commands.
- `SEM` stands for Set Emulation Mode. this command temporary changes the emulation mode.
- The `6` means HPIII emulation
- `EXIT` ends the execution

The following lines with `@PJL` indicate a "Print Job Language header".

The `M%!PS-Adobe-3.0` indicate that everything else is Postscript code.

You can print this file RAW to a printer but if you want to view it on screen you can take all the Postscript code and convert it to a viewable image.

For instance, you can use Ghostscript to create a PDF. Save all the Postscript code (so everything from %%Title onwards) to a file and execute gs.exe.

```
gs.exe -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite input-file
```

---

Edit: If you have 1500+ files you could use a batch file to convert them.
Assuming they are all in one directory, you can do something like this:

Create this convert.cmd somewhere:
Assumes your files are in C:\YOUR_RAW_FILES
Assumes they are all in one directory
Assumes gs is installed in C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.05\bin\ (change if other version)

```
@echo off

:: create a convert directory and remove contents
if not exist "C:\MYCONVERTS\" mkdir C:\MYCONVERTS
del /Q C:\MYCONVERTS\*.*

:: loop through all your files and pass the linenumber for %%Title to convert-procedure
for %%X IN (C:\YOUR_RAW_FILES\*.*) do (
  for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n "%%Title" %%X') do call :convert %%a %%X %%~nX
)

:: remove the temp files leaving the pdf files in MYCONVERTS
del /Q C:\MYCONVERTS\*.tmp

goto End
::--------------------------------

::================================
:convert
:: we need the lines above %%Title (so - 1)
set /a z=%1 - 1
:: export all remaining lines to .tmp (skipping the first x lines)
for /f "tokens=* skip=%z%" %%b IN ('type %2') DO @echo %%b >> C:\MYCONVERTS\%3.tmp

:: execute ghostscript with correct parameters
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gs\gs9.05\bin\gswin32c.exe" -o C:\MYCONVERTS\%3.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite C:\MYCONVERTS\%3.tmp

goto :eof
::================================

:End
```

I'm not sure if this will hold up if the files contain real binary information but you can try.

Comment: Worked perfectly, without the "gs" in front of the parameters.
Any idea on getting all this done on 1500+ files, without having to open and save them all by hand?

Comment: @user450387 Ok, in that case you entered it in Ghostscript interactive program itself. The gs (or gs.exe) would be needed if you ran this from a command prompt or from a batch-file. In your case you would need to strip the front of the file and feed the rest to gs.exe in a batchfile. Are you familiar with batch-files?

Comment: @user450387 I also added a batchfile to convert multiple files (it contains comment so you can understand what is done).

Comment: Oh sure, thanks. I got kinda stuck on the way.. The batch does not work, hence there are some errors on the echo. But i dont want to bother you doing my work, so i decided to write a little C# Console application that handles all that stuff. (And because i dont know enough about batch-programming, so it will be easier for me to understand and debug) I'll update my question with the code one i'm done.

Comment: Do you have any idea how i could setup a "Virtual" printer to create such postscript-Printer files for me? I have tried doing this with the Driver that was given there "Kyocera Mita FS-1020D KX" and several others, but i always end up with a "PCLXL" formated file.

Comment: @user450387 In the Gostscript directory \gs\gs9.05\lib there are two files ghostpdf.inf and ghostpdf.ppd which can be used as "pure" postscript drivers for a printer. No PCLXL whatsoever. The resulting file can be perfectly used with ghostscript itself.

Comment: @user450387  And if you want to automate generating PDF files via a program you can use the Redmon port driver. In that case you don't choose file or USB as printerport but the Redmon port. In Redmon you can configure it will start your program when it receives a postscript file. That's how the pdf-creator printers do it. http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ghost/redmon/index.htm