# Generate a Printer File In Postscript for "Kyocera Mita FS-1020D KX"

Tags: printer, postscript, print-drivers

Im trying to generate a post-printerdriver file to send it to a printer "on demand". I figured out how to do this by redirecting the printeroutput to a file, that works ok. 
The problem is that i cant get the driver to generate the filecontent in postsript, i always end up with PCLXL.

The printer im tring to generate for is a "Kyocera Mita FS-1020D KX" and the generated file should look like the one I posted [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1248563/what-format-is-this-file-starting-with-r-sem-9exit-and-how-to-display-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a PCL driver, the output will be PCL, not PostScript. Your printer does support PS, but Kyocera call it "KPDL". Select the KPDL driver for your OS here:

https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/index/service/dlc.false.driver.FS1020D._.EN.html

For Windows Vista and later you will need to use the Universal driver. Looking at the file structure of the ZIP file, you will need to install it via the Add Printer Wizard, as an unlisted, local printer. For the port, create a Standard TCP/IP port with the printer's IP address, or use the existing one if it already exists. When asked for the printer model, point it at the KPDL folder in the ZIP.

Comment: Thanks, that looks a lot more like the file im trying to create. But still there are some diffrences, for example the header is missing the first line "!R! SEM 9;EXIT;" it seems to be important, or isnt it? Anyways ill try with this file on the costumer system!

Comment: It worked, so the "!R! SEM 9;EXIT;" - part does not seem to be necessary.

Comment: PostScript only starts at the line that says "!PS-Adobe-3.0". The lines above it, that start with "@" are PJL commands. They are used to set the printer in a specific mode, including specifying PostScript as the language. The top line are Kyocera commands, as per the answer to your other question.